# Faking a Mirror Using Cameras

Tags: camera

I'm working on an NPR animation with the lineart modifier and have a short section involving the camera looking into a mirror. Typical mirrors in Blender wouldn't reflect the lineart modifier so I'm trying to figure out a workaround using a camera mirrored to the main camera in the scene and compositing that output after render.

This would be relatively easy using constraints on the 'mirror' camera but the mirror rotates slightly as well making the x/y axis bound constraint break the illusion by not adjusting for the perspective of the 'mirror' object.

Is there a way to solve for this? Also is there an easier way to go about getting a mirror result with lineart and I've just over complicated things?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am ALMOST there. I found if I follow this I can get it 95 percent there.

Create a plane at the origin (the mirror)

Create an empty (Empty A) and a camera (Camera A) and parent Camera A to empty A. Move it along the Y axis away from the origin (mirror)

Create another empty (Empty B) and another camera (Camera B) and parent camera B to empty B.

Copy location constraint on Empty B targeting Empty A with Y inverted

Copy rotation constraint on empty B with Z and X inverted

Child of constraint on Empty B targeting the mirror object (plane)

This all works so that if Empty A (Primary View) moves Empty B (mirror view) mirrors it's movement along with it and rotates accordingly. If the mirror plane itself rotates then the Empty B (mirror view) changes perspective along with it.

You can render both of these out and use cryptomatte with the plane to composite the Mirror view in afterwards.